# new thread causes issues c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, sleep, thread-sleep

I have a `void` function that has a `while (true)` loop inside of it, and both `Sleep();` and `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds());` do nothing. And yes, I am aware I'm sleeping by **millisecond** and not seconds, by multi-threading I mean I have done:

```cpp
std::thread nThread(Void);
nThread.detach();
```

When I just call the method, this issue doesn't occur, and it sleeps just fine.

Essentially what I'm doing:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>

void thisisVoid()
{
    while (true)
    {
        printf("Print");
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread nThread(thisisVoid); 
    nThread.detach();
}
```

Comment: Could you please make a [mre]?

Comment: Unrelated: On many systems sleeping for a single millisecond is going to be disappointing. `std::this_thread::sleep_for` guarantees that you wait ***at least*** that long. The underlying system will not be able to give you a tick that precise and you could find the program sitting around for 10 or more ms waiting for the next tick. Test carefully to see how long your sleeps usually are.

Comment: Unrelated (probably): Be careful with `detach`. You lose control of the thread and depending on what you're doing in the thread you may not want it to do whatever your system does with threads orphaned when the executable exits.

Comment: Not enough information to provide anything better than generalities. Certainly not enough information to assist in debugging your program. We need a [mre] at a minimum. Threading gets weird, and without a complete-and-executable example of the bad behaviour and a good description of the desired behaviour  we can't help effectively.

Comment: What is `std::thread nThread(Void); nThread.detach();` supposed to do? I can't see that compiling.

Comment: i gave an example in the post

Comment: You should probably clarify what you mean by `"i have another issue"`.  And what's `While` -- `c++` is case sensitive?  Please make sure you show the *real* code.

Comment: There is no problem in this code. It works as expected. Try to find the documentation and understand what "detach" does and what is the opposite operation.

Comment: You detach the thread which means that the main program doesn't need to wait for it.  And then you end the main program which causes the OS to kill all your threads before they can do anything.  You probably don't want to end the main program until some time is passed.  If you use join instead of detach the main program will wait forever since the thread never ends, so detach is the right thing.  Have a look at this: https://onlinegdb.com/rJxn81ueZO

Comment: The program as presented, once the typos are cleaned up, will create the thread and exit before the thread even gets a chance to start. You need to do more reading on when to use `join` and when to use `detach`. The short answer is you almost always use `join`. If you `join`, you may be fooled by the data you're `printf`-ing being buffered. Eventually the buffer will fill up and you'll get hundreds or thousands of "Print"s all at once in a huge block.

Comment: "_both `Sleep();`_" - Mmm... no they don't.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the sleep that's the problem. You haven't really asked a question, but I think what you're saying is that if you don't detach, you get a crash.

Here's why...

C++ doesn't like you to exit the program with dangling threads. You can either detach them or join them. There's a startup time with your new thread, and if you just exit main at the bottom, your first thread probably hasn't run yet. And it hasn't been allowed to clean up because you haven't joined against it or detached it.

So you have to do one or the other in main(). If you join against it you'll wait until it's done. If you detach it, you could exit before he's even executed.

Comment: so either way i'm screwed- join is absolutely not what i'm looking for because it's a while true loop, it's not a while something is temporarily false loop

Comment: @INeedHelp You're probably not screwed. There are a few million programmers successfully writing multithreaded programs in C++. But you haven't really explained what your real problem is. Perhaps you should edit your question with more information as to what you're actually trying to accomplish.